# PHP wordpress template - add default image if none selected

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Apologies, I am relatively new to PHP and am learning as I go, but am stuck on this... I have this template for a page-title section with a background image. I can add the background image, but if there is no background-img:url elected on the page, is there a way to write in a default background-img:url into this template?

```
<section class="page-title" <?php if($bg):?>style="background-image:url('<?php echo esc_url($bg);?>');"<?php endif;?>>
    <div class="auto-container">
        <h1><?php if($title) echo balanceTags($title); else wp_title('');?></h1>
        <div class="bread-crumb">
            <?php echo convo_get_the_breadcrumb();?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before your code:

```
if(empty($bg)){
    $bg = '/path/to/your/default/image.jpg';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="page-title" <?php if($bg):?>style="background-image:url('<?php echo esc_url($bg);?>')" <?php  else: ?>
style="background-image:url('your URL')"
<?php endif; ?>>
```

Comment: Do I add a separate line for the default URL if there is no URL found?

Comment: as you see wordpress add the bg image with a function using if statement then you can use else to put your default bg image

Comment: Thanks very much. Sadly, this breaks the page; perhaps its not possible in this theme.

Answer (score 0):

Using @psdev's code, I was able to add in a default background-image if $bg was empty. Thanks!!

```
<section class="page-title" <?php if(empty($bg)){$bg = 'http://aqmenalt.mhsites.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Banner-10.png';} if($bg):?>style="background-image:url('<?php echo esc_url($bg);?>');"<?php endif;?>>
    <div class="auto-container">
        <h1><?php if($title) echo balanceTags($title); else wp_title('');?></h1>
        <div class="bread-crumb">
            <?php echo convo_get_the_breadcrumb();?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can now remove the second if, if($bg) because its always true ;)